# Is there a way to optimize the operator+= for different data types

Tags: c++, templates, containers, operator-overloading

"I'm not a pro, I'm just learning!"

I want to support add operator in my class like Buffer.

```
class Buffer : public vector<uint8_t>
{
public:
    Buffer() = default;

    Buffer& operator += (const char* str)
    {
        auto pStr = str;
        while(*pStr)
        {
            emplace_back(*pStr);
            ++pStr;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T>
    Buffer& operator += (const initializer_list<T>& ByteArray)
    {
        this->operator+=<vector<T>>(ByteArray);
        return *this;
    }
    template<class OtherContainer>
    Buffer& operator += (const OtherContainer& ByteArray)
    {
        std::copy(ByteArray.begin(), ByteArray.end(), std::back_inserter(*this));
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T, size_t size>
    Buffer& operator += (const T (& arr)[ size ] )
    {
        std::copy( std::begin( arr ),  std::end( arr ), std::back_inserter(*this));
        return *this;
    }
};
```

I want to override for:

```
int main()
{
    vector<uint8_t> vec = {48,49,50,51};
    string str = "45";
    char arr[] = {60,61,62,63};
    Buffer b;
    b += vec;
    b += str;
    b += "67";
    b += {56,57,58,59};
    b += arr;

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to write one beautiful template for all cases? Or at least combine into one "initializer_list", "vector", "string"? Maybe somewhere you can avoid "copy" and use "move"?

Comment: Container, and c-array might be combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use C++20, then you can use `requires` to minimize those functions as much as possible.

```cpp
class Buffer 
    : public std::vector<uint8_t>
{
public:
    Buffer() = default;

    template<typename T>
    Buffer& operator+=(const T& any)
        // Any container that has iterators or arrays.
        requires requires { std::begin(any); std::end(any); }
    {
        std::copy(std::begin(any), std::end(any), std::back_inserter(*this));
        return *this;
    }

    // This is a must if you want to allow:
    // b += {1, 2, 3};
    // And to not force the user to specify it's an initializer list:
    // b += std::initializer_list{1, 2, 3};
    template<typename T> 
    Buffer& operator+=(const std::initializer_list<T>& list)
    {
        std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(), std::back_inserter(*this));
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Also, the first overload is going to accept **any** container that has iterators.

Note that I didn't check the type in the containers, so if you do something like:

```cpp
struct S{};
std::vector<S> vec;
b += vec;
```

This would result in an unpleasant error.

To move the data you can simply replace `std::copy` with:

```cpp
std::move(std::begin(any), std::end(any), std::back_inserter(*this));
```

Comment: Using `std::begin(any)` instead of `any.begin()` allows to regroup C-array with regular containers.

Comment: if used with a C-string, the '\0' is inserted, which I would like to avoid

Comment: @victer `std::begin` and `std::end` are both pointers, so you can reduce the end pointer by 1 to eliminate the `\0` that is being inserted on C-style strings.
Here is an example: https://godbolt.org/z/T8TMsx

Comment: all arrays can be reduced by 1 (`if constexpr (std :: is_array_v <T>)`). How to check only on C-string? (`b += "67"; // 67\0`  - reduced by 1, `but char arr[] = {60, 61, 62, 63}; b +=  arr;` - not reduced)

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice that.
Then you can add another if statement that checks if the last character is `\0`.
https://godbolt.org/z/W3xWfj . I would probably recommend making a function for that, rather than just have both of them there, just to beutify things a bit.

Comment: that's bad too :( Because `char arr[] = {60, 61, 62, 0}` should not reduced. You need to decrease what was initialized in quotes i.e. "something  c-style string". Ok, thk! You taught me so much already)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, the second example does not remove any characters other than `\0`, `0` is not the same as `\0`.
`char arr[] = {60, 61, 62, 63}` is being printed just fine.

Comment: your example `if(*end == '\0')` only works with  O3 optimization and not work O0(((( [link](https://godbolt.org/z/YsTjcK)